# Google Data Studio Pie Chart and Donut Chart Cross Filtering Error | System Error

Tags: charts, pie-chart, looker-studio, donut-chart, system-error

Suddenly, today i cannot interact with this specific donut chart. Before, it works fine.

[image]

When I tried to click on the part of the chart, for ex: Distribution Agreement, usually it will do a cross-filtering among all the other charts. But, today it will result in the error below. But, the other charts are filtered successfully based on the "Distribution Agreement" category.

[image]

In between clicking and turning into an error, I saw there was 2 lines of red error that only lasted like 1-2 seconds and then disappear. I then quickly took a screenshot and got this picture.

[image]

If I tried to change the Pie/Donut chart into a bar chart and interact with it. The result is that it is successful and does not show any error.

[image]

Does this mean that currently there is an error when interacting with the DONUT/PIE chart? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The issue is **No Longer Reproducible**. For future reference, this was a [temporary issue (fixed on 22 Apr 2022)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/229861822) that affected users during the 4th week of April 2022. In future, post bugs and issues on the official [Google Data Studio  Issue Tracker](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7340016)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On 25th April 2022, this problem is already fixed by Google Data Studio

Comment: The issue is **No Longer Reproducible**. For future reference, this was a [temporary issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/229861822) that affected users during the 4th week of April 2022. In future, post bugs and issues on the official [Google Data Studio  Issue Tracker](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7340016)